# Pie charts in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I couldn't find any examples or documentation for/about pie charts in plotly. Anyone knows if they are simply not implemented yet?

I actually never ever had a use case for them until today.

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/SayaliSonawane/Plotly_Offline_Python/tree/master/Pie%20Chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, they aren't implemented yet. The polar wedge charts are close, but each wedge has to be the same width: https://plot.ly/python/polar-chart/#Polar-Area-Chart[image]

In the meantime, that type of categorical data can sometimes be visualized with stacked or grouped bar charts: https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/#Grouped-Bar-Chart

Answer (score 1):

A pie chart implementation for Python is already available at Plot.ly:

https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/